# All of my CSS transitions end abruptly on mouse out

Tags: css, css-transitions

I can never get my CSS transitions to work on mouse out/off hover. It works fine on hover but not the other way around.

```
.btn {
    border: 1px solid #5a5350;
    background: #FFF;
    color: inherit !important;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: #FFF !important;
    background: #f79e43;
    border: 1px solid #f79e43;
}
```

What's the problem with my code?

Thanks

Comment: [Looks fine to me](http://jsfiddle.net/CZS2z/)

Comment: Same here in Chrome on Win7 - http://jsfiddle.net/UAqSG/

Comment: Maybe you wanted all attributes, not only background to fade? http://jsfiddle.net/jnL2U/

Comment: add transition property to the hover state maybe (so you'll have transition on `.btn` AND `.btn:hover`)?

Comment: the jsfiddle above works fine but using the exact code on my page doesn't, it just works for the hover over of the button. Adding the transition to the hover property also doesn't make any difference. Any ideas?

Comment: Could something be overlapping your button then?